# Dequeuing seems to do 8 nodes at once when it should only dequeue a single node

Tags: javascript, linked-list, queue

I am trying to dequeue the top node in my list and assign it to a variable.

In this fiddle `x` should just equal 2 but it's equaling 3 through 10.

```js
var Node = function(_content) { //makes the object node

  this.content = _content; // contains the contents of the node
  this.next = null; // pointer that points to the node infront of it
  this.last = null; // pointer that points to the node behind it
  this.ID = null;
}

function Queue() {

  this.top = null; //head of the list 
  this.bottom = null; //tail of the list
  this.length = 0; // length set to zero

  this.toString = function() { // turns objects into strings
    var str = ""; //creates the string that the content will be passed to
    var node = this.top; //makes the node it checks the node at the top of the list

    while (node != null) { //goes through each node
      str += node.content; //puts contents of node into str
      node = node.next; //sets current node to the next node
    }
    return str; //returns a string of all the content
  }

  this.enqueue = function(_content) { // adds a node to the back of the queue
    var newNode = new Node(_content); //creates a node with the content that was passed through
    if (this.length === 0) { //checks the length to see if its zero
      this.top = this.bottom = newNode; //this tells the queue that this node is both the top and bottom
    } else {
      this.bottom.next = newNode;
      this.bottom = newNode; //makes new node the bottom
    }
    this.ID++;
    this.length++; //the length of the queue will increase by 1 every time a new node is added
    return this;
  }
  this.dequeue = function() { //takes a node off the top of the queue
    if (!this.bottom) return this; //if there are no nodes at the top it will return itself
    if (this.length === 0 || this.top === this.bottom) { //checks if its at the last node
      this.top = null; //sets the top to null
      this.bottom = null; //sets the bottom to null
    } else {
      this.top = this.top.next; //sets this node to be equal to the next node on the queue
    }
    this.ID--;
    this.length--; //decreases the length by one each time a node is removed
    return this;
  }

  this.getLength = function() {
    return this.length
  }
  this.peek = function() {
    return this.top && this.top.content;
  }
  this.hasElements = function() {
    if (this.length > 0)
      return true
    else
      return false
  }
  this.topElem = function(_content) {
    return this.top.content;
  }

  this.getID = function(_content) {
    return this.ID.content;


  }
}

function main() { //happens when user clicks button
  var n = document.getElementById("value").value; //it grabs the input
  debugger;
  var q1 = createQ1(n); //creates the first queue using a unique function
  var q2 = new Queue(); //creates the second function using the standard function
  //adds debugging functionality

  printQueue(q1, 0, 1); //calls the printing function
  printQueue(q2, 0, 2); //calls the printing function
  sieveAlgorithm(q1, q2);

}

function createQ1(n) { //creates the queue 1
  var myQueueOne = new Queue(); //creates an empty queue
  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) //adds to the queue up to n starting from 2
    //  parseInt(i);
    myQueueOne.enqueue(i); //adds all the numbers to the queue
  return myQueueOne; // returns numbers to q1

}

function printQueue(qList, itr, qnumber) { //function for printing out the queue. qlist = the queue, itr = iteration, qnumber = 1 since we passed it through
  var string = ""; //creates empty string
  if (qnumber == 1) { //creates the template
    string = "Iteration " + itr + ": Q1 = ";
    string = string + " " + qList;
  } else {
    string = "  Q2 = "
    string = string + qList;
  }
  var header = document.createElement("h3");
  var t;
  if (qnumber == 1) {
    var att = document.createAttribute("id");
    att.value = "itr" + itr;
    header.setAttributeNode(att);
    t = document.createTextNode(string);
    header.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(header);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("itr" + itr).innerHTML = document.getElementById("itr" + itr).innerHTML + string;
  }
}

function sieveAlgorithm(q1, q2) {
  var counter = 1;
  var lengthOfq1 = q1.getLength();
  var x = q1.dequeue();
  q2.enqueue(x);
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = x;
  printQueue(q1, 1, 1);
  printQueue(q2, 1, 2);
}
```

```html
<input type="textbox" id="value" value="10" />
<input type="button" id="push" value="Add N" onclick="main()" />

<br><br><br>
<p id="output"></p>
<p id="output2"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you expect your `dequeue` method to return the dequeued value, but it does not return that, it returns the queue itself (`return this`).

So either change what `dequeue` returns, or use the `peek` method to get the value that will be dequeued before actually doing so. In the second case, replace this:

```
  var x = q1.dequeue();
  q2.enqueue(x);
```

with this:

```
  var x = q1.peek();
  q1.dequeue();
  q2.enqueue(x);
```

### Remarks

- Use class syntax
- Nodes don't need to be doubly linked. A singly linked list is enough for a queue
- Make Queue iterable -- this makes the `toString` a simple method
- Don't use comments that state the obvious, like "checks the length to see if its zero". Comments should explain things at a higher level, they should not just translate the code in English.
- In `dequeue`, the condition `this.length === 0` will never be true, as that case was already dealt with by the preceding `if`.
- Don't use the pattern: `if <boolean expression> return true; else return false`. Instead just return the boolean expression.
- The `topElem` method should not have a parameter. The goal is to *return* content, not to get it.
- Don't mix I/O with the class. The class should only provide the `toString` method, but it should not create DOM elements. Separate I/O from algorithm concerns.

Here is how the above points can be dealt with. This code does not use HTML, it just runs the test with `n=10` and outputs the results to the console:

```js
class Node { // Use class syntax
    constructor(content) {
        this.content = content;
        this.next = null; // In a queue there is no need for a link to previous node.
    }
}

class Queue {
    constructor(...values) { // Allow caller to already specify content for queue
        this.top = null; 
        this.bottom = null;
        this.length = 0;
        // Populate the queue with any values that were provided
        for (const content of values) {
            this.enqueue(content);
        }
    }
    * [Symbol.iterator]() { // Make queue iterable -- handy for toString
        let node = this.top;
        while (node) {
            yield node.content;
            node = node.next;
        }
    }
    toString() { // Make use of above iterator
        return Array.from(this).join("->") || "(empty)";
    }
    enqueue(content) {
        const newNode = new Node(content);
        if (this.length === 0) { 
            this.top = this.bottom = newNode;
        } else {
            this.bottom.next = newNode;
            this.bottom = newNode;
        }
        this.length++;
        return this;
    }
    dequeue() {
        if (this.length === 0) return null; // Don't return `this`
        const content = this.top.content;
        if (this.top === this.bottom) {
            this.top = this.bottom = null;
        } else {
            this.top = this.top.next;
        }
        this.length--;
        return content; // Return the value, not the queue
    }
    peek() {
        return this.top?.content; // Use the optional chaining operator
    }
    hasElements() {
        return this.length > 0;
    }
    topElem(_content) {
        return this.top.content;
    }
}

function main() {
    const n = 10;
    // Create the values on the fly and pass them to the constructor
    const q1 = new Queue(...Array.from({length: n - 1}, (_, i) => i + 2));
    const q2 = new Queue();
    console.log("Q1 is " + q1);
    console.log("Q2 is " + q2);
    // Now dequeue provides the content that was removed from the queue
    q2.enqueue(q1.dequeue());
    console.log("after moving one value:");
    console.log("Q1 is " + q1);
    console.log("Q2 is " + q2);
}

main();
```